# does an object created in a parameter to function get copied to both stacks?

Tags: c#, oop

If class x calls y by going y.create(new z) does the z obj get created in x's stack as well as y's? This is assuming we are passing by value, not ref or ptrs

Comment: Can you put actual code?

Comment: Where is `y` going..? on a field trip.. do you mean `doing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

The stack/heap is on the process (application) level, not at an object level. The entire application shares one stack (at least in the context of your question), no matter how many objects it is using.

Unless the "z" in your example is a value type (like a struct), it won't ever fully reside on the stack. If "z" is a class, then it "lives" on the heap, with only a reference to it on the stack.

You really should read [this short explanation from Jon Skeet](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html), especially "A worked example" towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The object z is created in the applications allocated memory. Each function does not have its own memory area when using new to create objects.

I would suggest that you read up on the content on [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/79-the-stack-and-the-heap/) page, I certainly find it useful from time to time (ie when i get things mixed up)

Comment: `ots` or `its` you have a typo `it's and its` are `!=`

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Comment: will be +1 when you add discussion on value types since it is not clear from the question if it is strictly for reference types (as your current answer) or for value and reference types ("we are passing by value" can be understood both ways). Boxing of value types for bonus point :)